# perl split function returns infinite array

Tags: arrays, perl, split

I think there's a bug here. I have a string consisting of numbers separated by ':'. when I use split(), the number of list items is not a number, it returns "1289,2235,2300,2336". What's wrong here?

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl

$data="10:2284:2345:2381:9:2235:2300:2336:8:2212:2273:2320:7:2194:2262:2295:6:2165:2232:2269:5:2118:2167:2205:4:2086:2142:2161:3:2039:2106:2138:2:2034:2088:2127:1:2028:2079:2109:01:1999:2046:2080:02:1972:2016:2052:03:1960:1987:2019:04:1915:1945:1971:05:1870:1888:1911:06:1798:1828:1855:07:1764:1789:1809:08:1692:1728:1753:09:1665:1688:1706:010:1636:1657:1679:011:1575:1607:1641:012:1549:1582:1620:013:1485:1539:1582:014:1395:1485:1540:015:1382:1456:1504:016:1368:1422:1465:017:1301:1360:1405:018:1267:1252:1283:019:1213:1252:1283:020::1159:1180:021::1112:1143:022::1087:1094::";

@l = split(':',$data);

print scalar @l ;
```

Comment: I have tried it and it returns 128. Looks like you print somethin else later in your code. And because you have no line break at end of your print statement it will be connected to the output of `print scalar @l ;`

Comment: Works for me as well. The stuff you print later appears in your original string after the 4th colon.

Answer (score 6):

Your code works fine for me - I get `128` printed when I run it.
I think the thing that will be tripping you up is that you don't print a line feed. E.g. `\n` or use `say`.

So your number is:`1289,2235,2300,2336` which implies *this* bit of the code is printing  `128` and elsewhere in your code is printing `9,2235,2300,2336`.

If you can extract more of your code, and produce an MCVE - minimal complete verifiable example - the fine folk of StackOverflow can help you further. I *suspect* when you do this, your problem will disappear - whilst there are bugs in perl, it's quite a mature language and so the bugs really don't show up unless you're doing something particularly obscure.